# Non embeddability of a rectangle

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Let us denote $R$ to be a rectangle, i.e. topological boundary of a set of the form  $[a,b]\times[c,d]$ in $\mathbb R^2.$ I want to show that given any rectangle $R,$ there does not exist any topology on $R$ and smooth structure on it such that the natural inclusion map $i:R\to\mathbb R^2$ is not an injective immersion.

I can definitely solve this if the topology of $R$ is the subspace topology induced by $\mathbb R^2$. Then I can choose a corner of the rectangle and show that the tangent space is two dimensional at that point, which is not possible. How to solve the general case?

Comment: Your first sentence is indecipherable — way too many negatives. Please proofread and clarify. And most of us mean by rectangle the two-dimensional figure $[a,b]\times [c,d]$. I am guessing from your second paragraph that you're talking about the boundary (i.e., the union of four $1$-dimensional intervals)? So the point is that this $1$-dimensional manifold *with corners* does have a smooth structure (choose a homeomorphism with the circle), but that smooth structure does not play well with the inclusion map to $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Your second paragraph is only almost accurate. The argument you have in mind shows that $R$ isn't a *submanifold* of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but this is a stronger hypothesis than it just carrying the subspace topology and an arbitrary smooth structure. As Ted remarks, it is possible to put a smooth structure on $R$ with the subspace topology and in fact one can even do this in a way that makes the inclusion smooth - the crux is that it can't be an immersion. To see this, take a corner point, pick a chart around it and look at difference quotients to show the derivative in that chart vanishes.

Comment: What is difference quotients?